# PHP Echoing Long of String With Limited Output?

Tags: php, echo, partial, flush

I have a **variable of array** containing such as these **names**;

```
// Listing ENTITIES
$entitiesTable = array(
    1 => "user",
    2 => "group",
    3 => "customer",
    4 => "supplier",
    5 => "terminal",
    6 => "order",
    7 => "invoice",
    8 => "invoice detail",
    9 => "invoice offer",
    10 => "invoice offer detail",
    11 => "quotation",
    12 => "quotation detail",
    13 => "quotation offer",
    14 => "quotation offer detail",
    15 => "purchase order",
    16 => "purchase order detail",
    17 => "purchase order request",
    18 => "purchase order request detail",
    19 => "sales order",
    20 => "sales order detail",
    21 => "delivery order",
    22 => "delivery order detail",
    23 => "sales return",
    24 => "sales return detail",
    25 => "purchase return",
    26 => "purchase return detail",
    27 => "item",
    28 => "category",
    29 => "unit measurement",
    30 => "last activity",
    31 => "rack",
    32 => "alert",
    33 => "filter",
    34 => "prefix code",
    35 => "system",
    36 => "company profile"
);
```

And at the middle of my php body, i create For Loops. **Iterating** the array, and then **echoing** em out.

```
foreach ($entitiesTable as $singleEntity){
if(preg_match($regexUsed, $singleEntity)){
    $pluralEntity = preg_replace($regexUsed, 'ies', $singleEntity);
} else {
    $pluralEntity = $singleEntity . 's';    
}

// Replacing spaces with a dash character and capitalize the first word
$pluralEntityWOSpace = ucwords($pluralEntity);
$pluralEntityWOSpace = str_ireplace(" ","" , $pluralEntityWOSpace);

$pluralEntityWDash = str_ireplace(" ","-" , $pluralEntity);

$singleEntityWOSpace = ucwords($singleEntity);
$singleEntityWOSpace = str_ireplace(" ","" , $singleEntityWOSpace);

echo $singleEntityWOSpace . '<br/>';
}
```

Somehow, I just realized it right now, that **What i obtained is NOT A WHOLE NAME** as it's listed earlier from the array. Instead, **What I got now is just a small piece of those names**. Look! 
Here are the **output names I obtained**:

```
User
Group
Customer
Supplier
Terminal
Order
Invoice
InvoiceDetail
InvoiceOffer
InvoiceOfferDetail
Quotation
QuotationDetail
QuotationOffer
QuotationOfferDetail
PurchaseOrder
PurchaseOrderDetail
PurchaseOrderRequest
PurchaseOrderRequestDetail
SalesOrder
SalesOrderDetail
DeliveryOrder
DeliveryOrderDetail
SalesReturn
SalesReturnDetail
PurchaseReturn
PurchaseReturnDetail
Item
Category
UnitMeasurement
LastActivit
```

I tried to write **FLUSH()** at  the end of my **php script**, and the output of those names are OK. But then it gives me **another error**, since I'm using **Slim Framework**. 
Is there another alternatives way rather than using **FLUSH()**?

Comment: Probably some quirky output buffering. Write ob_flush( ) at the end of your script to see if that works.

Comment: ya i tried it already, but seems it is the limitation of Slim Framework when we're dealing with ECHO while it hasn't been executing the Slim()->run() method.

my echo is limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real quick answer for this is, by modifing the php.ini file;

```
output_buffering = 4096
implicit_flush = Off
```

And then restarting the APache server. I dunno why but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for somewhat called [CamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase),
here is a string to camelcase function:

```
function to_camel_case($str, $capitalise_first_char = false) {
  if($capitalise_first_char) {
    $str[0] = strtoupper($str[0]);
  }
  $func = create_function('$c', 'return strtoupper($c[1]);');
  return preg_replace_callback('/_([a-z])/', $func, $str);
}
```

Taken from: http://www.paulferrett.com/2009/php-camel-case-functions/

Comment: thanks for the camel case @Dan Lee... but the problem is the "Echoing process". It doesn't Echo all of the text correctly.